# Matching everything but a specific word

Tags: regex

I've got this regex:

```
.*js/[\bpackaged\b]+\.js
```

At the moment it matches 'packaged.js' from the list below:

- js/foo.js
- js/bar.js
- js/suitcase.js
- js/bootstrap.js
- **js/packaged.js**

How can I invert this so that it matches all the others except for 'packaged.js'?

Comment: Note that your pattern also matches "js/ppppppp.js".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kent$  echo "    js/foo.js
    js/bar.js
    js/suitcase.js
    js/bootstrap.js
    js/packaged.js
"|grep -P '.*js/.*(?<!packaged).js'

    js/foo.js
    js/bar.js
    js/suitcase.js
    js/bootstrap.js
```

the example is just showing the expression, if you really use grep, -v could make it easier.

--- **updated based on  glibdud's comment** ---

notice the last 5 lines in input:

```
 kent$  echo "    js/foo.js
    js/bar.js                                                                                                                            
    js/suitcase.js                                                                                                                       
    js/bootstrap.js                                                                                                                      
    js/packaged.js
    js/foo_packaged.js
    js/packaged_bar.js
    js/foo_packaged_bar.js
    js/_packaged.js
    js/packaged_.js"|grep -P '.*js/(.+packaged\.js|.+(?<!packaged)\.js)'
```

output:

```
    js/foo.js
    js/bar.js
    js/suitcase.js
    js/bootstrap.js
    js/foo_packaged.js
    js/packaged_bar.js
    js/foo_packaged_bar.js
    js/_packaged.js
    js/packaged_.js
```

Comment: If I'm reading it right, this will match any filename whose base doesn't _end_ with "packaged". In other words, it would also fail to match "foopackaged.js". Good example, though. May be good enough for the OP's purpose.

Comment: Good solution, although I think you need to change the first ".+" back to ".*" or else it will fail to match the case where "packaged" is preceded by a single letter (e.g. "js/apackaged.js")

Comment: @glibdud +1!  thanks for pointing it out! updated, but still with `.+` ^_^

Comment: Amazing! Regex is always one of those things that gets me most of the time :)

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
.*js/(?!packaged\.js).+\.js
```